# SIG<SOMETHING> to show configuration

Tags: linux, unix, signals, posix

It's a common practice to utilize SIGHUP when reloading a daemon configuration. But what signal is better to use for other tasks, like e.g. showing configuration: SIGINFO, SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2?

UPD. Will use USR1

Comment: dd accepts USR1 to display progress

Comment: Also suggest SIGUSR1. I wouldn't recommend SIGINFO - on some systems, it's a synonym for SIGPWR (power failure).